# Android - How get wave form of Speech Recognition

Tags: android

I would like to know a method to get the waveform at the time the user uses the Speech Recognition.

Edit: I tried this api (https://github.com/Semantive/waveform-android)

Comment: This question doesn't follow the SO standards. We need to see what specifically you have tried, including in Android since there are a good number of code examples out there.

Comment: @zgc7009 Well, I've used one api: https://github.com/Semantive/waveform-android , sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @GuilhermeG., please edit your question as zgc7009 has suggested, and for further help, see “[How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.

Comment: No need to apologize it can take a try or two to figure this site out. Google your question, or look through SO specifically for a similar question, see what they have done, try it, and if it fails come to us with what you tried and what exactly didn't work about it.

Comment: @zgc7009 Thanks! =)